# How to get bold text in the title in CardAction

Tags: .net-core, botframework

Is it possible to get bold text in the title of a `CardAction()` in bot framework v4? I'm using it in a HeroCard. I've tried ** Option One ** but it only works in the text of a `HeroCard` for example, but not in the `CardAction()` buttons.

Here's my implementation of `CardActions` in a `HeroCard`:

```
var Options = new HeroCard
        {
            Text = "What do you choose?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Option One, Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = ""Option One" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Go back", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Go back" },
        },
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It's up to each channel to determine how to display cards.

Alternatively, you can try using an [Adaptive Card](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) with something like the following JSON:

[image]

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "What do you choose?"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Option One",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "size": "Large",
                            "color": "Accent"
                        }
                    ],
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit"
                    },
                    "id": "optionOne",
                    "style": "default"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Go back",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "size": "Large",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "color": "Accent"
                        }
                    ],
                    "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "data": "goBack"
                    },
                    "id": "goBack",
                    "style": "default"
                }
            ],
            "style": "emphasis"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Again, though, it will be up to the channel for how it wants to display `"weight": "Bolder"`